# Empty "Forums" page BuddyPress site wide forums - bbPress

Tags: buddypress, bbpress, forum

The main "Forums" page where all forums are supposed to be listed is empty.
[image]
What have I missed here or the combination of BuddyPress and bbPress caused this page not to work anymore?

I have followed the installation guide here http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/installing-group-and-sitewide-forums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out

In BuddyPress installation guide, it says I needed to delete "Forums" WordPress page so I did.

Turn out that "Forums" page held on to mywebsite.com/forums permalink although it was already trashed.

So I went into phpMyAdmin and change the slug of the page to forums1 and guid to mywebsite.com/forums1 (I'm not sure if changing guid is necessary) and then created a new page with name "Forums". Now this new page can have permalink mywebsite.com/forums I can insert shortcode `[bbp-forum-index]` as Sarah Gooding pointed out [here](http://wpmu.org/guide-to-buddypress-forums-how-to-set-up-group-or-sitewide-forums/)

Alternatively, I believe you can bring the "Forums" page back to life (Hi BuddyPress, why should we delete the "Forums" page in the first place?) and choose default template (just don't wanna mess with BuddyPress templates) and insert the same shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've got very similar issue. The forums page was blank. The problem was caused by some another plugin (maybe BuddyPress) which created empty forums page. Thus bbPress have not replaced the page with it's own version.

In my case the solution was just to insert **`[bbp-forum-index]`** into the page content.

Comment: Why do you think that your solution will work for this question? Can you explain?

Comment: Because I had same symptoms as described in the question, and the solution worked for me.